# Replacing PTFE tube in Mk8 heatbreak

Tags: heat-break

I am trying to replace a Mk8 heatbreak on my printer. But which orientation do I need to put into the heatblock? The left image or the right image? Note that this specific heatbreak is missing a PTFE tube.

[image]   [image]

I quickly looked at the other questions on this forum but could not find a clear result with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PTFE liner should be in contact with the nozzle, and is normally cut half a millimetre over-size to ensure that it remains in contact.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. To make it absolutely clear, that means that the right picture should be screwed into the heatblock, right?

Comment: @zwep Yes. That end should be partially stopped, so that the PTFE tube cannot pass through it (but the filament can).